# Not able to use element attributes( props ) in React

Tags: html, reactjs

this is my input element with key & categoryname attributes

```
<input 
  className="is-checkradio is-circle" 
  id={item.CategoryID} 
  key={item.CategoryID}
  categoryname={this.props.node.CategoryName}
  type="radio" name="categoryCheckBox"
  onClick={this.UpdateCategory}
/>
```

I want to pass them to prop function in `onClick` event `UpdateCategory`

```
UpdateCategory({ target }) {
    console.log(target);
    console.log(target.categoryname);
    this.props.UpdateManualCategory(target.id, target.categoryname);
}
```

But value in categoryname is undefined & not sure why key is not shown

[image: logs]

Comment: Are you able to print `this.props.node.CategoryName` ?

Comment: Why just not pass these 2 params into the function `onClick={() => this.UpdateManualCategory(item.CategoryID, props.node.CategoryName)}}`

Comment: @utsav : it will not serve the purpose, Tam : same for you , can't use the category name from props as it is multilevel tree component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute that is not a predefined attribute on the element cannot be obtained from `target` directly. And although `id` is a predefined attribute on input, but `categoryname` isn't

In order to access them, you need to use the `getAttribute` method

```
UpdateCategory({ target }) {
    this.props.UpdateManualCategory(target.id, target.getAttribute('categoryname'));
}
```

Comment: thanks mate , it worked. But still wondering why the `key` attribute is not shown in log and still its value is not fetched

Comment: key attribute is a special attribute used by React  and is not passed down on to the elements as attributes or Components as props and hence you don't see it in the log

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
      UpdateCategory(e) {
        e.persist();
        const target=e.target;
        console.log(target);
        const category=target.getAttribute('categoryname')
        console.log(category);
        this.props.UpdateManualCategory(target.id,category);
     }
```

Comment: can you please check that you are getting valid output for this.props.node.CategoryName or not?

Comment: can't use the category name from props as it is multilevel tree component

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this way:

```
const {node, UpdateManualCategory} = this.props
...
<input 
  className="is-checkradio is-circle"
  key={item.CategoryID}
  type="radio" name="categoryCheckBox"
  onClick{()=> UpdateManualCategory(item.CategoryID, node.CategoryName)}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is solved. Please go to below url and you will get code for your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qz4i2x

I hope it will solve your problem.